# Matlab 2014b on Ubuntu 14.04 busy idenfinitely

Tags: 14.04, matlab

When Matlab 2014b is loaded and ready to be used, as soon as I issue a command (any command, even quit) it gets stuck and remains 'busy' indefinitely.

Installation is fine I didn' get any errors. I am running Matlab locally.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to the use of the proprietary ATI radeon graphic driver. For some reason, with that driver activated, MATLAB was not responding to any command.
Switching back to the xorg ATI driver everything works fine.